# SVN Compare JS not working

Tags: svn, ibm-rad

I am using Version: 7.5.5.5 iFix1
Build ID: RADO7555iFix1-I20120913_1613 and all of a sudden I am unable to compare JavaScript files. It was working, now it just hangs on intializing compare editor. I tried removing settings, and reinstalling subclipse. No joy.

Answer (score 0):

Does the compare feature works for other SCMs? Perhaps Git? or even Local history? Wondering if SVN plugins were corrupted.

Moreover, if there is a problem in RAD I'm sorry to say you won't get help from IBM because it has reached its end of service date

http://www-01.ibm.com/software/support/lifecycleapp/PLCDetail.wss?synkey=W170532D29019M02-L603472G19375Q17-M054243E02973V75